# Как прижать блок к краю который повернутый по вертикали?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, нужно сделать вот такие вкладки (prntscr.com/gm666f). Они должны быть прижаты к краю окна и находится в секции с контентом поэтому position: fixed не подходит. То есть, [есть вот такая разметка](http://jsbin.com/faceniduli/edit?html,output).
Я пробовал задать секции position: relative; а диву с кнопками position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; transform: rotate(-90deg); что бы его повернуть, но он не прижимается к краю, попробовал добавить right: -26%; столько нужно чтобы прижать к краю блок, но если изменить разрешение все едет, этот вариант не сработал. Так на сколько я понял он не прижимается из-за transform. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.buttons {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%; top:0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space: nowrap
}

.buttons span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='buttons'>
    <span>Обратная связь</span>
    <span>Отзывы</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, то что нужно !